# Change the name of an object within an archive

Tags: aix, oracle-12c

My company has some software that uses a 3rd party library to interact with an oracle database.  It hasn't been tested in a long time, and now that we need to verify that it's working, we can't get the 3rd party library to connect to Oracle in our AIX environment, but it works in windows and linux.

Our software is 64 bit, the 3rd party is 64 bit, and the Oracle client is also 64 bit.

I have the 3rd party code, but only for debugging purposes, not for production/release.

When calling dlopen to load the main oracle archive, I get this error:
 0509-022 Cannot load module /home/OracleTest/libclntsh.a(shr_64.o).
        0509-152   Member shr_64.o is not found in archive

Everything on the internet I've been able to find says that (shr_64.o) is for 64 bit objects, and (shr.o) is for 32 bit.

But, when check the archive, I see that the 64 bit archive has a shr.o instead of an shr_64.o

bash-4.3$ ar -X64 -t -v libclntsh.a
rwxr-xr-x 94110/42424 61808612 Oct 30 17:32 2014 shr.o

The 3rd party code hard codes in shr_64.o for 64 bit.  If I change it to shr.o, the code all works as expected.

Because I can't change the 3rd party code, I'm looking for a way to update the object within my archive to be named shr_64.o instead of shr.o